# GeoServer: Gradient legend for polygons with gradient fill

Tags: geoserver

I have a GeoPackage layer of polygons that is colored by a numeric attribute `xy` with this SLD:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>Style McStyleface</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Name>Test</Name>
      <Title>Test style</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
             <Fill>
               <CssParameter name="fill">
                 <ogc:Function name="Interpolate">
                   <!-- Property to transform -->
                   <ogc:PropertyName>xy</ogc:PropertyName>

                   <!-- Mapping curve definition pairs (input, output) -->
                   <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
                   <ogc:Literal>#ff0000</ogc:Literal>

                   <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
                   <ogc:Literal>#000000</ogc:Literal>

                   <!-- Interpolation method - defaults to linear -->
                   <ogc:Literal>color</ogc:Literal>

                 </ogc:Function>
               </CssParameter>
               <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.7</CssParameter>
             </Fill>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

So far, so good--the map is rendered accordingly. Now, I was looking for a legend that represents the gradient nature of the data, but could only find so [for raster data](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/index.html#raster-legends-types). In the examples that are shipped with the software all gradient legends are in combination with raster data, while vector data are mapped to discrete factors. So, my question: how is it possible to generate a gradient legend for vector data with GeoServer?

| In figures, I am aiming to achieve this... | ...rather than this: |
| --- | --- |
| [image: gradient] | [image: discrete] |

Would be great if anyone could give me a hint :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is (currently) any way to do this as the legend generator doesn't have access to all the features to get the required range of values in an interpolate function. Looking at the [code](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/c98467248a24701611f1d5d0f20fe5ea075e43a0/src/wms/src/main/java/org/geoserver/wms/legendgraphic/BufferedImageLegendGraphicBuilder.java#L155):

```
final boolean buildRasterLegend =
                (!strict && layer == null && LegendUtils.checkRasterSymbolizer(gt2Style))
                        || (LegendUtils.checkGridLayer(layer) && !hasVectorTransformation)
                        || hasRasterTransformation;
```

Looks like it explicitly excludes all vector transformations from the legend.

I suspect that adding code to do that would be difficult, but if you want to take a look then [BufferedImageLegendGraphicBuilder](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/c98467248a24701611f1d5d0f20fe5ea075e43a0/src/wms/src/main/java/org/geoserver/wms/legendgraphic/BufferedImageLegendGraphicBuilder.java) would be the place to start.

Comment: Thank you for the very prompt response, Ian Turton!
Okay, good to know this limitation of GeoServer. Unfortunately I'm untrained in Java and moreover, I lack the time to dig into the code (although it is tempting :D). Luckily, with Leaflet there is a workaround that I will post as an additional answer in case it might be useful for someone...

Answer (score 0):

[As shown by the accepted answer, gradient legends for vector data are currently unsupported by GeoServer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/422342/97303). I found a simple workaround with Leaflet (in my case the R package `leaflet`): it is possible to render the legend with Leaflet, while the vector layer is provided by GeoServer.

Lacking a real MWE<sup>1</sup>, I will leave an exemplary code snippet here instead: the data (`data`) are handled within `R` and are used to create the color palette `pal` with the numeric variable `data$value`. `data`is then passed to GeoServer to update the layer `layer_xy` of a GeoPackage in a [Geopackage data store](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/geopkg/input.html) (note: this part is skipped here). Finally, Leaflet renders the map and the legend and calls GeoServer that serves `layer_xy` via WMS:

```
library(leaflet)

pal <- colorNumeric(palette = colorRamp(c("#ffffff", "#ff0000")),
                    domain = data$value)

leaflet() |>
  addTiles() |>
  addWMSTiles("http://localhost:8080/yourlinktoGeoServer/wms?service=WMS",
              layers = "layer_xy",
              options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png",
                                       transparent = TRUE)) |>
  addLegend("bottomleft",
            pal = pal,
            values = data$value) |> 
  setView(lat = 31.4, lng = 31.8095, zoom = 11)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> can't see how I could achieve this due to the dependency on GeoServer...